# Multiple updates during one function call in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write some script performing quite heavy computations. Thus, I'd like to inform user about progress by updating content on the site (for example, fraction of completed computations). Is it possible to achieve with JavaScript? Does JavaScript allow update of the content while invoked function is still running? Or maybe no matter what are the circumstances I can update the content only after invoked function is done?

Comment: You can modify the screen in between statements.

Comment: @ATOzTOA: More precisely, you can modify the DOM in between statements, but it will not be rendered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at workers: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

It's made for heavy computation (at javascript scale ofc), and comes with some functions for updating the user about the state of the computation, it's multithreading in javascript basically.

Comment: Wow, that's really nice! It looks like very convenient tool for problems exactly like the one I have. I'm surprised that I haven't come upon workers while looking over the Internet for the solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Use [timers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Timers)

From your computing function, update global variables.

Then from main thread, use `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` to query the global value periodically and update screen.

Answer (score 0):

While your function is running, no screen updates will happen: UI thread has to fight for its time just like any other JS thread. You can do it by scheduling callbacks:

```
function f() {
  a();
  // update now
  b();
}
```

can be rewritten as

```
function f() {
  a();
  setTimeout(function() {
    b();
  }, 0);
}
```

The way this works, after `a()`, `setTimeout` will schedule the rest of the function, then exit. This is where UI thread can (and will) now grab control; then after it is done, the scheduled remainder will execute.

If you have things to do that fit the (quite severe) WebWorker restrictions, you can use them instead; however, they cannot touch UI, so redraws would be pointless (unless you do as Antoine says, and schedule an update function based on WebWorker-calculated parameters).

Comment: Webworkers cannot draw on the main thread, right, but they don't need to. They can send signals periodically to this main thread, which can catch them into event listeners, and redraw the UI.
The main advantage of this approach is that you make sure that you'll never block the main thread.

Comment: @Antoine: "unless you do as Antoine says and..." But if your code is not too complex, WebWorkers are overkill, and breaking up code into schedulable pieces is sufficient.

Comment: Oh yeah, I've seen that part, don't get me wrong. I just wanted to add this precision about the interaction with the main thread.
About the fact that it can be overkill, I agree, the OP talked about "quite heavy computation" though.

Answer (score 0):

My few cents:

- The easiest method to address is the most common way of simply
  showing a busy animation.
- Try breaking your heavyweight computational code into pieces & update
  the progress bar.
- Or as *Antoine* suggested, try using [Web Workers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/).

Comment: Busy animation will not animate if you don't relinquish the thread.

Comment: True.But, I was thinking in the lines of : http://www.phpied.com/css-animations-off-the-ui-thread/

Comment: Currently unsupported in overwhelming majority of browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, probably you can do it. I don't know all details of your problem, but you should be aimed to [socket.io](http://socket.io/) and asynchronous [node.js](http://nodejs.org/).

With **node.js** you can send process states to clients in real time and catch server responses with **socket.io** on client-side.